# what is type of new object in constructor in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

how to Item class in $modal type in typescript?
modal is the new object.
but, how to modal object type in Item constructor?

```
class Modal {
  constructor() {
   this.$modal = document.querySelector(`#modal`) as HTMLElement;
  }
  openModal() {
    this.$modal.style.display = 'block';
  }
}


class Item {
  constructor($modal) {
   this.$modal = $modal;
 }

  init() {
  this.$modal.openModal();
 }
}

const modal = new Modal();

const item = new Item({$modal: modal});
```

Comment: `const item = new Item(modal.$modal);`

Comment: I want to Modal class in openModal method. how to type in constructor $modal??

Comment: This should work in `Item` class: `constructor($modal: Modal)`